# How to use/integrate Allwrox reach application in my local system for testing Addtapi.net tools?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, winforms

I will use AddTapi.net tools in asp.net C# application.

I have set the Allwrox reach app in my Android mobile phone for incoming call and transfer call (I created the Allwrox server in my local system). Can I use addtapi.net tools for incoming call and transfer call functionality? Does anyone know how to use Allwrox app (installed in Android mobile phone with server name, user, password) in C# for addtapi.net tool testing?